# Post files were deleted but still being served on gatsby develop

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gatsby

i have a gatsby site and that had some old posts that i wanted deleted , i have deleted them now and when I run `gatsby develop` i still see those posts on the front end and the posts page. When I search for the old posts i can see there;s lots of copies in a folder static /d/

[image: lots of copies in this folder shown here]

1. How can I get rid of old posts the right way
2. If I delete that folder d inside the static folder it will show other errors as shown below

`

```
C:AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gatsby-cli\node_modules\yoga-layout-prebuilt\yoga-layout\build\Release\nbind.js:53
        throw ex;
        ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:public\static\d\561\path---index-6a9-aDDrNa0DGjvA7EyGkpTSkXD4tkY.json
    at readCachedResults (E\node_modules\gatsby\dist\utils\websocket-manager.js:21:24)
    at getCachedPageData (E:node_modules\gatsby\dist\utils\websocket-manager.js:49:13)
    at Socket.getDataForPath (Enode_modules\gatsby\dist\utils\websocket-manager.js:147:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:528:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'E\public\\static\\d\\561\\path---index-6a9-aDDrNa0DGjvA7EyGkpTSkXD4tkY.json'
}

`
```

Thanks for your  help!

Comment: I have managed to do this by adding hide:true to the frontmatter, but id like more info on the above issue Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete cache folder and public folder before run develop